# React Native Animation undefined is not an object error

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native, css-animations

I am trying to animate a view to slide right when a button is pressed, I currently have the below code but keep getting

undefined is not an object ( evaluating this.state.panelPos) error. I dont understand what is wrong with the code. Any suggestions?

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        initialLife : 200,
        panelPos: new Animated.Value(0),
    };
};


slideOutPanel(){
Animated.timing( this.state.panelPos,{
            toValue: 300,
            duration: 1000,
        }).start();
};

render(){return(
<View style = {styles.container}>

    <View style = {styles.lContainer}>

        <View style = {styles.playerLife}>

            <View style = {styles.lifeButtonRow}>
                <LifeButton/>
                <LifeButton/>
            </View>
            <View style = {styles.lifeButtonRow}>
                <LifeButton/>
                <LifeButton/>
            </View>     

            <Text>text</Text>
        </View>

        <Animated.View style = {[styles.panel,{transform: [{translateX: this.state.panelPos}]}]}>
            <Image style = {styles.cmd_panel} source={require('image')}/>
        </Animated.View>
    </View>
    <View style = {styles.portrait}>
        <Button title = {'push'} onPress = {this.slideOutPanel}/>
    </View>
</View>);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise everything seems to be correct, but context of **this** is not correctly set on: `onPress={this.slideOutPanel}`.

Either: `onPress={() => this.slideOutPanel()}`

or: `onPress={this.slideOutPanel.bind(this)}`